# Model association that spans across parent app and engine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-engines

I'm making a Rails engine that makes reference to the `current_user` in a controller like so:

```
require_dependency "lesson_notes/application_controller"

module LessonNotes
  class NotesController < ApplicationController

    def index
      if current_user
        @notes = Note.where(student: current_user) if current_user.user_type.name == "student"
        @notes = Note.where(teacher: current_user) if current_user.user_type.name == "teacher"
      end
    end

  end
end
```

This is quite verbose and it would seem I could do something like this instead:

```
require_dependency "lesson_notes/application_controller"

module LessonNotes
  class NotesController < ApplicationController

    def index
      @notes = current_user.notes if current_user
    end

  end
end
```

However, *the user model exists in the parent app, not the engine*.

In the `Note` model I have this to define the `belongs_to` association:

```
module LessonNotes
  class Note < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :student, class_name: "::User"
    belongs_to :teacher, class_name: "::User"
  end
end
```

How would I define the other side of the association - the `has_many` - in the `User` model?

Comment: you usually do that via generators.  take for example devise, you run the install for devise and it prepends the necessary code in the model, ie `devise_for` ...

Comment: Ah, that's interesting. I think that would be a good idea if I were going to package up this engine to be reused in different apps, but this engine will only ever be mounted in one particular app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I ended up doing it...

In the parent app:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many   :notes, class_name: LessonNotes::Engine::Note, foreign_key: "teacher_id"

end
```

Comment: This helped me SO much. Thank you! My issue was with the rails engine model referencing another rails engine model. The "foreign_key:" trick worked!

Comment: Is there  anythying you need to do in the belongs_to association inside the `LessonNotes::Engine::Note`?